# Monitor WCF service with net.tcp endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We have a WCF service with a net.tcp endpoint and Azure's application insights monitor doesn't seem to work with it. Does it not work with net.tcp endpoints, or is there something we have to do to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Insights SDK does not support automatic collection of telemetry for net.tcp endpoints. You can implement it yourself by extending the WCF channel to collect the required information and send it to Application Insights using the TelemetryClient.TrackRequest method.

Answer (score 1):

While there's no official support for WCF, we've had an experimental SDK package that supports instrumenting WCF services out for a while: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-SDK-Labs/tree/master/WCF